# Miller compensation capacitor sizing

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, audio, bjt, common-emitter

How can I size the circled capacitor in order to get rid of the peaking?
Is there some formula?
Cheers

[image]

Comment: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/miller-frequency-compensation/

Comment: yes, i've seen that page but it isn't so straightforward regarding my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given;

- uncompensated discrete amplifier with closed loop gain of 20 dB , (R1+R2)/R1= 10x
- high Q resonance at 5MHz,
- ~20dB/decade rolloff >10MHz
- 0dB gain at 50 MHz which becomes the GBW product.

We could compute the open loop gain

- and determine the ω/RC breakpoint for some circuit Req and added Miller C to achieve 0 dB gain

  - and then expect 45 deg phase shift at unity gain at GBW/G = 50MHz for phase margin.
- **example**

  - if \$a_v=60dB\$ and 1st order = -20dB/decade above 50MHz the breakpoint *"at least"* must be less than 3 decades lower or 50kHz.  ( if 80 dB then 4 decades lower)
  - the Req=R29//hFE*R24 + R25
  - your C1 is then C1=1/(2π f*Req)

There will be tolerances for each transistor GBW in this design which determines the extra margin to reduce breakpoint. In typical BJT Op Amps , the breakpoint is 10Hz. For video Amps not unity stable it may be > 10kHz +

e.g.   The goal is to make the slope 1st order or phase shift <=90 deg at unity gain and eliminate the cascade stage higher order effects at high gain where negative feedback almost shifts into positive feedback "low phase margin"

[image]

[ref](https://www.nt.ntnu.no/users/skoge/prost/proceedings/acc04/Papers/0926_FrP01.1.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. could you expand "if av=60dB and 1st order = -20dB/decade above 50MHz the breakpoint "at least" must be less than 3 decades lower or 50kHz. ( if 80 dB then 4 decades lower)" a little bit? What is av for instance? Thanks

Comment: Av is a common term for Open Loop gain when the output is balanced and not saturated from DC offset

Comment: I am not certain this is the best criteria or how to explain how to choose or explain simple. but to eliminate the high Q peaking , it can be critically damped with a 1st order Miller cap filter. You can choose the value for unity gain stable as I did, or limit the minimum gain and use a smaller C if that is any benefit.. But the trick is to make it from 3 or more poles to 1 dominant pole

Comment: Isn't Req=R29||r_o_Q17||r_pi_Q16?

Comment: however I'm not sure about that the graph you posted. Shouldn't w'1 be referred to the loop gain graph (Aol*beta)?

Comment: maybe the dominant  low values are Req=hFE*R24+r_pi_Q16 + R25 while the other r_o's can be ignored (>100k ..>1M).

Comment: well  Aol * w'1   <= 1 * w'2 for unity gain stable then  I used the red Line to simulate (Aol*beta) of 40 dB closed loop